# array of objects are not being fetching when i press the fetch button in react

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, undefined, fetch

i got the error when running this !! It says cannot read property of map undefined . I want to run the fetch function when buton is pressed ! and then the objects will show.. but nothing seems like that.. it goes to error

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            robots: []
        }
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    }

//fetch data function . linked with button shdfvjksvda kvahsdksa
    fetchData=()=> {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {  response.json() })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
           this.setState({ robots: data })
        }
        )
        ;

    }

    render() {
        return (

           <div>
            <button onClick={this.fetchData}>Fetch</button>
            <p>
                {this.state.robots.map(el => {
                    return <div key={el.id}>
                       <span>{el.email}</span>
                       <span>{el.name}</span>
                       <span>{el.id}</span>
                    </div>
                })}
            </p>
        </div>
        )
    }

}

havscjhuvsakdvasdu
export default App;
```

Comment: my guess is the `.then(response => {  response.json() }` line. In this case you meant it by executing `response.json()` without making any manipulation on it (or returning anything for the next `then`). I would suggest taking care of `setState` here, e.g. `.then(response => {  this.setState({ robots: response.json() }) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Easwar pointed out, you're not returning anything from your first `.then()`. The ideal solution however is to just omit the `{` brackets, to have it automatically return the value. This is a bit cleaner, and more readable:

```
fetchData = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ robots: data })
        });
}
```

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.

See the [documentation for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more information on how they work.

Comment: yes thankYou Frankerz ! U just solve my problem 
I omit the {} brackets and the code had run .

Answer (score 1):

You missed the return statement while chaining promises.

```
fetchData=()=> {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => {  return response.json() })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
       this.setState({ robots: data })
    }
    )
    ;

}
```